# Can I get the Java type of a given Tag in dcm4chee?

Tags: dcm4che

Can I get the Java type of a given Tag in dcm4chee? Maybe from it's VR?

I already can get the VR of my tag:

`VR tagVr = VR.valueOf(myTagIntCode)`;

But I cannot get the ValueType of that VR, which could help me to know which exact type is the tag value.

Here is the VR enum declaration, ValueType is the second argument starting right:

```
    AE(0x4145, 8, ' ', StringValueType.ASCII, false),
    AS(0x4153, 8, ' ', StringValueType.ASCII, false),
    AT(0x4154, 8, 0, BinaryValueType.TAG, false),
    CS(0x4353, 8, ' ', StringValueType.ASCII, false),
    DA(0x4441, 8, ' ', StringValueType.DA, false),
    DS(0x4453, 8, ' ', StringValueType.DS, false),
    DT(0x4454, 8, ' ', StringValueType.DT, false),
    FD(0x4644, 8, 0, BinaryValueType.DOUBLE, false),
    FL(0x464c, 8, 0, BinaryValueType.FLOAT, false),
    IS(0x4953, 8, ' ', StringValueType.IS, false),
    LO(0x4c4f, 8, ' ', StringValueType.STRING, false),
    LT(0x4c54, 8, ' ', StringValueType.TEXT, false),
    OB(0x4f42, 12, 0, BinaryValueType.BYTE, true),
    OD(0x4f44, 12, 0, BinaryValueType.DOUBLE, true),
    OF(0x4f46, 12, 0, BinaryValueType.FLOAT, true),
    OL(0x4f4c, 12, 0, BinaryValueType.INT, true),
    OW(0x4f57, 12, 0, BinaryValueType.SHORT, true),
    PN(0x504e, 8, ' ', StringValueType.PN, false),
    SH(0x5348, 8, ' ', StringValueType.STRING, false),
    SL(0x534c, 8, 0, BinaryValueType.INT, false),
    SQ(0x5351, 12, 0, SequenceValueType.SQ, false),
    SS(0x5353, 8, 0, BinaryValueType.SHORT, false),
    ST(0x5354, 8, ' ', StringValueType.TEXT, false),
    TM(0x544d, 8, ' ', StringValueType.TM, false),
    UC(0x5543, 12, ' ', StringValueType.STRING, false),
    UI(0x5549, 8, 0, StringValueType.ASCII, false),
    UL(0x554c, 8, 0, BinaryValueType.UINT, false),
    UN(0x554e, 12, 0, BinaryValueType.BYTE, true),
    UR(0x5552, 12, ' ', StringValueType.UR, false),
    US(0x5553, 8, 0, BinaryValueType.USHORT, false),
    UT(0x5554, 12, ' ', StringValueType.TEXT, false);
```

I wanted to write something like this:

```
if (tagVr.getValueType().equals(BinaryValueType.DOUBLE)) {
    Double myDouble = dicomAttributes.getDouble(myTagIntCode, Double.NaN);
}
```

But now I'm feeling that I'm missing something. Can you point me the right direction?